# Kotlin - How to pass a Runnable as this in Handler

Tags: android, kotlin, handler, runnable

I'm beginner in kotlin. I try to create a task that will repeat every 2 seconds. So I created something like this.

```
val handler = Handler()
    handler.postDelayed(Runnable {
        // TODO - Here is my logic

        // Repeat again after 2 seconds
        handler.postDelayed(this, 2000)
    }, 2000)
```

But in postDelayed(this) it gives error - `required Runnable!, found MainActivity`. I've tried even `this@Runnable` but it didn't work.

But when I write the same function like this, it works

```
val handler = Handler()
    handler.postDelayed(object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            // TODO - Here is my logic

            // Repeat again after 2 seconds
            handler.postDelayed(this, 2000)
        }
    }, 2000)
```

So why the `this` keyword doesn't work in first function, but in second function it works good?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have several options to go about here:

1. make both the runnable and the handler be in the same scope

   ```
       //class scope
       val handler = Handler()
       val runnable = object : Runnable {
          override fun run () {
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null) 
            //make sure you cancel the 
             previous task in case you scheduled one that has not run yet
            //do your thing

            handler.postDelayed(runnable,time)
         }
      }
   ```

then in some function

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable,time)
```

2. You can run a `timertask`, which would be better in this case

   ```
    val task = TimerTask {
       override fun run() {
        //do your thing
       }
    }

    val timer = Timer()

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,0L, timeBetweenTasks)
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: But the first code is not working for me. It doesn't override run method.

Comment: In the first case, you still need `val runnable = object : Runnable { ... }`

Answer (score 3):

The first one is a function that accepts a lambda and returns a `Runnable`. In this case  `this` means nothing.

The second one you're defining an anonymous object that implements `Runnable`. In this case `this` refers to that object instance.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: @m0skit0 When you said 'The first one', did you mean `Runnable{...}` in the OP's first code example? If that's the case, could I ask you if there's any reference for this usage? Well, yeah in Kotlin we can omit a function's parenthesis if the argument is lambda, but I thought that's not a function, rather it's just a lambda, and the notation `Runnable` is just nothing but for avoiding confusion(I read it from Kotlin docs). Please let me know if I understood incorrectly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @starriet  `Runnable` is a [SAM conversion to lambda from a functional interface](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/fun-interfaces.html). It is equivalent to the second example, it's just syntactic sugar to avoid verbosity.

Answer (score 2):

The below example will work.

```
val runnable = object : Runnable { 
        override fun run() {
         
            handler.postDelayed(this,1000)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeap, when we create runnable in this way, we can get a reference to it by this keyword. But using lambda, it's not possible))

Answer (score 1):

In your case , when use **this** it means "*`local final class <no name provided> : Runnable`*" , refer to a header runnable.

```
runnable=object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                // i is a counter
                println("No. "+i++)
                // Repeat again after 2 seconds
                handler.postDelayed(this, 2000)
            }
        }
        handler.postDelayed(runnable,0)
```

Where `runnable` is used inside of a method. As `Handler()` is **deprecated**, we must use like this:

```
var handler: Handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
var runnable: Runnable = Runnable { }
```

Moreover, anywhere you can stop this method by:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
```